# How do browser extensions like Boomerang and Streak keep the current Gmail user authenticated

Tags: oauth-2.0

Boomerand and Streak and other similar browser extension apps that use oAuth2 to authienticate the user to google also have to authenticate the user to their backend servers. They dont use a separate login system to their web backend app.

I am assuming they piggyback on the initial oAuth2 traffic with google and set a 3th custom token to identify the user to their backend server.

It gets tricky when multiple gmail users sign in from the same browser. The extension must keep track of every gmail user and associate them with a new token.

Is this how they do it? What would your expert advise be on creating such a 3th token? I am thinking of taking the email address and whatever unique ID I can get from the client browser and encrypt this on the server to create a token for the user. Would this be secure enough? Do you have any better suggestions?